# React. getTime() function does not update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I' trying to update the state of the component `Demoss` by external function `getTime()`. I want to start update the time in the `state time` on the page load. And to make it real, I have invoke it in the `componentDidMount`. But for some reasons it does not happen.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './index.css';

function getTime() {
  let a = setInterval(() =>
    {new Date()}, 1000 
  );
  return a;
}

class Demoss extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      time: '',
      timer: false
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      time: getTime() // invoke setInterval state update, but it does not work
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(getTime());
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        timer: !prevState.timer
    }));

    if (this.state.timer === false) {
      clearInterval(this.timerId);
    } else if (this.state.timer === true) {
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.time.toString()}</p>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}><Dimes timer={this.state.timer}/></button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Dimes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.timer === true) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          Start timer again!
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          Start timer!
        </React.Fragment>
      );      
    }

  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Demoss />,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: does componentWillReceiveProps trigger ?

Comment: what do you mean? @h1b9b

Comment: What do you think `getTime()` is doing? [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) returns a reference to the timer it created, it doesn't emit the internal value or something similar. All `getTime()` currently does is create a timer that periodically creates a new date object and then does nothing with it.

Comment: @Nit Thank you, I understand it. But how we can make the function work? Explaine, please

Comment: @MaxWolfen I see you've commented that the logic needs to be an external function, why so?

Comment: @Nit It's just for the sake of a synthetic test. I did not find an answer either on the Internet or in the guide from React on how to use timers outside the component. So I'm trying to figure out if the timer is possible as an external function for the component. Say, to use this timer as a module in the future.

Answer (score 0):

by doing the following change it will update the time and re-render the component.

```
 let timeTicker = (self)=>  {self.setState({
    time:new Date().toString()
});}

class Demoss extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    let timer=setInterval(()=>timeTicker(this),1000);  
    this.setState({timer:timer});

 // keep the setInterval reference in state just so you can call clearInterval on this on `componentWillUnmount` hook
  }


  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.state.timer);
  }

}
```

`new Date().toString()` just to test I convert the date to string but you have to format it as a string before render I think.

I did omit `handleClick` func you can figure it out

Comment: I need an external function, not internal in `componentDidMount`

Comment: @MaxWolfen please check now, I move the function outside the component but yet you need to pass the reference of the component to it hope it's not an issue for you.

Comment: Very interesting solution, but I cannot figure out how it works...  Can you describe more about using `ref` in this way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code so i rewrote it.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Demoss extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      start_time: new Date(),
      now_time: new Date(),
      timer: false
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.timer = this.timer.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.timer, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // use intervalId from the state to clear the interval
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
  }

  handleClick() {
    const state = this.state;

    state.start_time = new Date();
    state.now_time = new Date();
    if(!this.state.timer)
      state.timer = true;

    this.setState(state);
  }

  timer() {
    if(this.state.timer)
      this.setState({ now_time : new Date()});
  }

  render() {
    const getTimeDiff = (start_time, now_time) => {
      return Math.round((now_time.getTime() - start_time.getTime()) / 1000);
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <p>{getTimeDiff(this.state.start_time, this.state.now_time)}</p>
        <Dimes handleClick={this.handleClick} timer={this.state.timer} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Dimes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const renderButtonText = timer => {
      let text = "Start timer";
      if (timer) text += " again!";
      else text += "!";
      return text;
    };

    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.handleClick}>
        {renderButtonText(this.props.timer)}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demoss />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I need an external function, not internal usage in `Demoss` component

Comment: You can change state from external func but can't setInterval